# Cannot install Grails from GVM on my Ubuntu machine; gvm install grails does not work

Tags: grails, gvm

I tried to use GVM tool to install Grails, and before that I updated GVM to the last version from a very old version. After the proposal of the prompt, I executed `gvm install grails` and it failed after a connection problem. I tried to install again Grails by typing the same command.

```
Found a previously downloaded grails 3.0.1 archive.
Not downloading it again...
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one 
of /home/myhome/.gvm/archives/grails-3.0.1.zip or
/home/myhome/.gvm/archives/grails-3.0.1.zip.zip, 
and cannot find /home/myhome/.gvm/archives/grails-3.0.1.zip.ZIP, period.
Stop! The archive was corrupt and has been removed! Please try installing again.
```

I executed again `gvm install grails` and it gave me the same error above, I tried to remove the files manually but I got an error that they are not found.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
gvm list grails
```

This will give you a list of all installed candidates. You should see an asterisk (*) symbol if you have candidates installed and an arrow to show which candidate is being used.

If they do show up. Try uninstalling it by specifying the candidate along with install

```
gvm uninstall grails 3.0.1
```

Then try running the install command again.

It usually does work.

Comment: The 3.0.1 version is not listed when I type gvm  list grails

Comment: Try gvm selfupdate. I can see 3.0.1 as a list of available candidates. Make sure you have not enabled the offline variable.